# calculating expected wait-times for uneven train arrivals (in real life!)

Tags: sequences-and-series, ring-theory, modular-arithmetic

Hello Mathematics Community,
I am not a mathematician. I work for a public transit agency as a data scientist. So my question might not be very novel, but maybe you will be motivated by the fact that I will use your answer to help schedule trains! I'll start by giving some background and context.

I am currently working on calculating the average wait time for passengers (arriving uniformly) to board a train. If we had only 1 line, running at a consistent frequency, say once every 8 minutes (aka 8-minute headway), the expected wait time is 1/2 the headway = 4 minutes.

Calculating expected wait time is also not hard if we have 2 lines running on the same tracks with the same frequency. For example, Stop X is served by the Green and Yellow line trains, both of which have scheduled headways (inter-arrival time) of 12 minutes. Assuming that the trains are spaced optimally, and assuming that the passenger can board either train to reach their destination, the effective headway would be 6 minutes, and the expected wait time would be half of that, 3 minutes.

This can generalize for interlining of 3+ train lines by taking the inverse of the sum of trains per unit time. So if we now add a third train line, say Purple at the same 12 minute headway, we would have 60/12 = 5 Green trains, 5 Yellow trains, and 5 Purple trains per hour, for a total of 15 train per hour, an effective headway of 60/15 = 4 minutes, and an expected wait time of 2 minutes.
$$\text{headway}_\text{eff} = \frac{1}{\sum\frac{1}{h}}$$

This is where things start getting trickier.

We are considering using **UNEVEN** headways on these interlined segments. So instead of 12-12-12 on Purple, Green, and Yellow, we are interested in 15-12-12, 6-8-10, or 3-7-9. Calculating the effective headway and expected wait times is now more challenging.

[This graph shows how wait times are distributed over time with 4- and 7-minute (uneven) headways](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4x8t.png)

We can no longer rely on the assumption that trains will be equally spaced. In most cases, it is inevitable that trains will periodically arrive at the same time. These are called "bangs" in rail scheduling jargon. From the passenger's perspective, 2 trains that arrive at the same time are practically equivalent to a single train (ignore crowding considerations). If two headways have a common factor, it is possible to avoid bangs by offsetting them so that they never arrive at exactly the same time. For instance, if we have 10-minute and 15-minute headways, we can offset them by 2 minutes from each other and know that they will never arrive at exactly the same time.

I figured out how to update the headway formula above to account for bangs. We can subtract out the bangs, which occur at the least common multiple (LCM) of the headways.
$$\text{headway}_\text{eff} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{h_1+h_2+h_3}-\frac{1}{\mathrm{LCM}(h_1, h_2)+\mathrm{LCM}(h_2,h_3)+\mathrm{LCM}(h_1,h_3)}}$$
In excel, I used IF statements to identify if two headways share a common factor:
=1/SUM(1/H1,1/H2,1/H3,IF(GCD(H1,H2)>1,0,-1/LCM(H1,H2)),IF(GCD(H1,H3)>1,0,-1/LCM(H1,H3)),IF(GCD(H2,H3)>1,0,-1/LCM(H2,H3)))

Although I have found the effective headway, the expected/average wait time is no longer 1/2 the headway, again assuming uniform arrivals. I made some basic simulations in Excel to validate this. I observed some interesting patterns in the simulations, but I have not been able to generalize my observations into a formula that I can use.

Here are some things I observed looking only at 2 interlined trains, e.g. 4-minute headway on Green and 7-minute headway on Yellow, assuming 1 passenger arrives per minute. See the linked image above for a graph of this scenario.

```
1. The average wait time must be weighted by the number of passengers. So, with uniform arrivals, the total passenger wait time would be the area under the curve divided by the time:
```

$$\text{total passenger wait time} = \frac{\sum\frac{\text{interarrivaltimes} ^ 2}{2}}{\text{time}}$$

```
2. The wait time is always equal or less than the smallest headway.
3. There is a repeating cycle of wait times, starting/ending with a "bang."
4. The length of this cycle (measured in terms of train arrivals) is x+y-1, where x and y are the headways
4. The sum of the wait times in the cycle is LCM(x,y)
5. There are x subcycles, each of which adds up to y, where x<y
6. The cycle contains all integers from 1 to x at least one time
```

That's about as far as I can take it. I haven't solved the formula for 2 lines, let alone 3+ interlined lines. Ultimately, I'm looking for a formula I can implement in python, but I'll take any guidance.

I have tried researching relevant topics. Although I haven't found any solutions, I believe that this problem is relevant to a few domains. Train arrivals are an arithmetic sequence, so interlined arrivals are the combination of multiple arithmetic sequences, which no longer have a common difference. The wait time between trains follows a cyclical pattern depending on the GCD and LCM, which pertains to modular arithmetic and rings.

Please bear in mind that I am not a mathematician, so I would greatly appreciate "dumbed down" responses that I can understand without googling all of the jargon, if at all possible!

Many thanks!

Comment: Just some quick thoughts...  If all headways have a GCD of 1, then you will guarantee that you will have a bang, and therefor the wait times will be the worst possible.  If you schedule all trains to to have the same headway, you can divide the headway time by the number of trains, and schedule each train to be staggered by this amount of time.  This should guarantee the best possible wait times for trains that all have that much headway.  I'd recommend to have all trains have the same headway in this simple situation.  Otherwise, things get complicated.

Comment: My comment above is assuming you want to minimize the _largest possible_ wait time.  If you are going for the smallest _average_ wait time, I think that you want to have each train with a different headway.

Comment: Thanks, Matt. I agree that using equal headways would allow us to stagger the trains so that they never bang. It also keeps things easier for our operations and is more predictable for passengers. However, we are being asked to model travel times and potential ridership gains/losses as a result of uneven headways.

Comment: In the simpler problem where the trains in $n$ lines arrive independently, uniformly at random, the mean wait time is $\bar{t}=\int\limits_0^{\operatorname{min}\{h_i\}}dt \ \left(1-\frac{t}{h_1} \right)\left(1-\frac{t}{h_2} \right) \cdots\left(1-\frac{t}{h_n} \right)$, where $h_i$ are the headways. When the train arrivals are dependent, it is significantly more complicated and you face a problem with $n-1$ variables (the 'delays') for $n$ lines. To see how that problem is phrased, see the [answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1558198/865701)